# Unmarshalling parcelables from an InputSream

Tags: serialization, inputstream, unmarshalling, parcelable, parcel

I have an `InputStream` (serialized bytes) containing marshalled `Parcel`s with `Parcelable`s inside them. I need to unmarshall and inflate the `Parcel` back up again so I can retrieve the `Parcelable`. How can I do this, when I don't know the length of the `Parcelable`? Is there a way to do this automatically just continuously reading from the bytestream?